# Google Tag manager Universal Analytics utmv cookie value

Tags: cookies, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I would like to access the utmv cookie value in Universal Analytics via Tag manager.  Reading this article here, I'm not sure this can be done.  Can anybody weigh in on this?  I want to use a First Party Cookie tag if possible with the value of "utmv".

http://www.optimizesmart.com/google-analytics-cookies-ultimate-guide/#Universal_Analytics_Cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the first value in a cookie called utmv by creating a new macro, set type to "first party cookie" and cookie name to utmv.

However if your intention is to get information from Universal Analytics this will not work. You can read utmv cookies that have been set by prior versions of Google Analytics, but UA will set only a single GA cookie (called by default _ga but might be renamed) which holds the client id as only value.

Comment: Is there any way to use the _ga client id to query session data with a different Google API?